# fs module writeFileStream not actually creating file on disk

Tags: node.js, fs

working on a small file transfer utility to replace an old email based system for order processing, and I'm using Nodejs, express, and a host of other libraries for this.

The current issue is that I have the data pulled over just fine, but I can't seem to actually save the file to disk at the end.

```
var file_url = `${config.poll.transUrl}/?location=${config.location}&transmission=${config.poll.transmission}`;
console.log(file_url);
var download_path = config.poll.folder;
var filename = setFileName();
var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(download_path + filename);
fileStream.on('finish', ()=>{
  console.log(`${filename} has been downloaded to: ${download_path}`);
});
http.get(file_url, (res)=>{
  res.on('data', (data)=>{
    console.log(data.toString());
    fileStream.write(data);
  })
  .on('end',()=>{
    fileStream.close();
    fileStream.end();
  });
});
```

Here's the code that I've been using, and it's just a snippet. Assume that all variables are set and are of the correct type, as I've ensured that is the case here.

According to what I understand, the `fileStream.end()` function is supposed to close the stream and save the file to disk, but it doesn't do so. I look in the folder where it's supposed to be, and nothing.

Also for more information, here is my config object:

`module.exports = {
  location: 'CA',
  watch:{
    folder: './watch/',
    transUrl: 'http://localhost:3289',
    transmission: 'send'
  },
  poll:{
    folder: './recieve',
    transUrl: 'http://localhost:3289',
    transmission: 'receive'
  }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is with `pipe`:

```
http.get(file_url, (res) => {
  const filePath = path.join(download_path, filename)
  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath)
  res.pipe(writeStream)
    .on('error', (e) => console.error(e))
    .on('close', () => console.log(`file was saved to ${filePath}`))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found a workaround:

Final code ignores the concept of adding to the stream as the data comes in as the data is purely text in the current implementation.

Final code is as follows:

```
  var file_url = `${config.poll.transUrl}/?location=${config.location}&transmission=${config.poll.transmission}`;
console.log(file_url);
var download_path = config.poll.folder;
var fileContent = '';
var filename = setFileName();
var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(download_path + filename);
fileStream.on('finish', ()=>{
  console.log(`${filename} has been downloaded to: ${download_path}`);
});
http.get(file_url, (res)=>{
  res.on('data', (data)=>{
    fileContent += data.toString();
  })
  .on('end',()=>{
    fs.writeFile(path.join(download_path, filename), fileContent,(err) =>{
      if(err){
        return console.error(err);
      }
      console.log('file was saved')
    })
  });
});
```